# How to remove black border around plots/graphics in ggplot2? R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggthemes

I'm creating some plots but every one I make has a black square border? How can I make this border white or remove it completelty?

Here is my code

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = hp)) + 
  theme_clean(base_size=18)
```

Here is my output plot that pasted into paint and used red arrows to point at the black border around my plot

[image]

How can I remove the black square border?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit the `plot.background` element of `theme`, changing `color` to white

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
data(mtcars)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = hp)) +
  theme_clean() +
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(
    color = "white"
  ))
```

[image]

Comment: That will work, but I want to use theme_clean() for its other features. Using theme_classic() gets rid of all the other formatting

Comment: @FruityPebblePug I have edited the answer to work with `theme_clean`